# cannot 'ls' /mnt directory

Tags: filesystems, files, directory, ls

I have a CentOS-6 machine that I'm working on that is running a live database.  It's having a problem with the `/mnt` directory.  I cannot `ls` the directory for some reason.  `stat` is working and shows this output:

```
  File: `/mnt/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca02h/51714d    Inode: 16321       Links: 9
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2011-09-23 06:50:20.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2012-10-29 11:46:33.000000000 -0500
Change: 2012-10-29 11:46:33.000000000 -0500
```

I can also `cd` into the directory and issue both the `touch` and `mkdir` commands successfully (or at least without errors. However, if I try to run `ls` in the directory it just hangs.  At that point neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> have any effect and my system locks up. I have to close my ssh window and reconnect to do anything else.

I'm at a bit of a loss here, does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?  Or, does anyone know how I can try to fix it, without rebooting the machine (I've encountered this once before on the same directory on a different machine and it was corrected by rebooting) since this is a live machine, I can't actually reboot.

These are the filesystems which are mounted in that directory:

```
blob.XXXXX.com:/blend on /mnt/blend type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
blob.XXXXX.com:/new_log on /mnt/new_log type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
blob.XXXXX.com:/new_backup on /mnt/new_backup type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
blob.XXXXX.com:/vz on /mnt/vz type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
blob.XXXXX.com:/git on /mnt/git type fuse.glusterfs (rw,allow_other,default_permissions,max_read=131072)
```

Interestingly enough, the output of `strace ls /mnt` shows the mount directories in there.

Comment: What filesystems do you have mounted?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xgqYsrLC

Comment: Have you managed to get it to freeze under strace? (with --color=auto or some other option)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is, `ls` attempts to `stat()` every file *within* the directory (which includes, in this case, the root of every mounted file system), which neither of the commands you attempted successfuly do so. So the problem is likely with one of the mounted filesystems, and not with `/mnt` itself.

To know more, you need to figure out what filesystems you have mounted in `/mnt`, and try each of them individually (`ls -d /mnt/foo`) to see which one causes the problem.

Comment: Neither of them seem to be having an issue.

Comment: so if you `ls -d` everything in /mnt, one at a time, none of them freeze? And if you `ls /mnt` again it still freezes again?

Comment: Can you pastebin the strace output? Maybe this will show where it freezes.

Comment: Yup, that's about right.  Here's the strace outupt:
http://pastebin.com/k39WGub7

Comment: @0x783czar When you run `strace ls`, it bypasses your shell aliases. You probably have an alias that causes `ls` to actually execute `ls --color=auto` or some such. The alias causes `ls` to stat each directory entry; a bare `ls /mnt` doesn't.

Comment: Yet, I was able to stat every file in the directory manually.  (there were only about 7 as can be seen in the strace output, unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' that's an amazing insight ! Thanks ! running `\ls` (to bypass aliases) runs it instantly, whereas the color made it hang due to NFS not being available